# Injecting a local variable to a binding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set a local variable to an existing binding

```
def foo_callback
  lambda { |name| p name }
end
b = foo_callback.binding
```

The binding doesn't have any local variables to begin with:

```
b.eval("local_variables") # => []
```

Let us set a primitive local variable to the binding:

```
b.eval("age=30")
```

Everything works as expected:

```
b.eval("local_variables") # => ["age"]
b.eval("age") # => 30
```

Now, let us try to set a non-primitive local variable to the binding:

```
country = Country.first
b.eval("lambda {|v| country = v}").call(country)
```

**Note:**  The [technique](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/binding/op_get.rb#L22) for setting the variable is borrowed from the `facet` gem. I tried the ruby 1.9 safe [implementation](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/binding/with.rb#L7) with same results.

The binding does not reflect the local variable `country`.

```
b.eval("local_variables") # => ["age"]
```

How do I get around this issue?  Essentially, I want to declare a new variable in a binding using the value of an existing, non primitive variable.

I am on Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: binding() is private, so binding can never be called like this: `b = foo_callback.binding`

Comment: @7stud You can. Run the code in the ruby console `def foo_callback
  lambda { |name| p name }
end
b = foo_callback.binding`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating `country` outside of the binding, and then the `country` inside the `lambda` is only valid within that scope. Why not `eval` it if you need to inject that into the binding as well?

**Update**

Try declaring the variable outside of the scope of the `lambda` but inside the scope of the binding:

```
 b.eval("country = nil; lambda {|v| country = v}").call(country)
```

Comment: `eval` takes string as the parameter, so I can't pass the value of an existing variable by reference. The code I am using is quite similar to the one used in the `facet` gem: https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/binding/op_get.rb

Comment: The remark about *facets* not working in 1.9 is not encouraging. Bindings are very important in Ruby but I've always found that there's only a very poorly thought out system for manipulating and using them. I've updated my answer with a rough stab at a solution.

Comment: I got the same results when I used the ruby 1.9 safe implementation: https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/binding/with.rb#L7

Comment: +1. I tested your solution in 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 it works in both versions. I have feeling that the `facets` implementation has a bug as there is no way it can work as it stands..

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're creating a new lambda, within another lambda, and that's creating a new scope.

To be more clear, the binding, 'b', will have in its scope all local variables available in the scope of the function #foo_callback, and all the local variables available in the first lambda. The second lambda that you created is a new scope, and therefore new local variables created in that scope aren't persisted outside of the scope unless they're initialized outside of the inner scope first.

That's why you'll see lots of people initialize local variables as nil before entering a block. You can also do this, which does the same thing:

```
country = country
{...block that sets country to something non-nil...}
return country
```

Instance variables don't have this scope issue, and are available throughout a function's inner and outer scopes.

Ex:

```
b.eval("lambda {|c| @country = c}").call(country)
b.eval "instance_variables"
```

should work.

And, someone beat me to the answer while I was writing this :)